# Execute command from string variable in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have got this code in file `scr.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
string='ps -e | less'
$string
```

And when I execute this script it doesn't work. Why? What I should do to execute command from string variable in shell script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to store commands in functions rather than in variables. Functions are great at it. Variables, not at all.

```
string() {
    ps -e | less
}

string
```

You could use `eval` to execute a command that has redirections (`>`, `<`) and pipes (`|`), but I strongly discourage you from doing so.

```
eval "$string"    # please don't
```

Comment: Or if it isn't too much to fork then a simple `bash -c $string` would suffice. Although this method is not as good as a function, it will do the job nonetheless.

Comment: I should also mention, `bash -c $string` is as bad as `eval $string`.

Comment: Why don't use `eval`? Only it works in this case. Because really I need to read `string` from keyboard, doing something with it and then execute.